# Convergence of $(1+\frac{1}{n+a_n})^n$, where ${a_n}$ is a real bounded sequence, for $n\to\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

How to approach this proof? My idea for the first step was to use the squeeze theorem:

$\exists_{M \in \mathbb{R}} \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : |a_n| \leq M$, since $a_n$ is bounded, then

$(1+\frac{1}{n+M})^n \leq (1+\frac{1}{n+a_n})^n \leq (1+\frac{1}{n-M})^n$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I prove that both the left and right expression converge to $e$?

Comment: For each of the two limits, just change $n$ to $n\pm M$. Then you'll have a $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ term and then a $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{\pm M}$ term. Clearly the second goes to $1$

Comment: That, or use that $M\leqslant\varepsilon n$ for every $n$ large enough, for every positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Did, that seems rather intuitive to me, but I cannot see how to use that in a formal proof.

Comment: @mathworker21, this is a very clear method indeed.

Comment: You would reach inequalities such as $$\left(1+\frac1{n+a_n}\right)^n\leqslant\left(1+\frac1{(1-\varepsilon)n}\right)^n\to e^{1/(1-\varepsilon)}$$ and likewise for the lower bound. Then, considering the limit $\varepsilon\to0$ would yield the conclusion. Just an alternative point of view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $|a_n|\le A\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$$
\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+A}\right)^n}_{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+A}\right)^{n+A}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+A}\right)^{-A}}
\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+a_n}\right)^n
\le\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-A}\right)^n}_{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-A}\right)^{n-A}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-A}\right)^{A}}
$$

Comment: this is what @mathworker21 suggested, right?

Comment: I read what you wrote in your question and this seemed the indicated way to continue. I hadn't read the comments beforehand since [they are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130975/are-comments-ephemeral-and-what-should-be-done-with-informative-comments) and answers can be lost in a comment thread. But to answer your query: yes, it appears similar.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way. Use the fact that $\ln(1+t)=t+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$: 
$$\begin{align}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+a_n}\right)^n&=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+a_n}\right)\right)=\exp\left(n\left(\frac{1}{n+a_n}+o(1/n)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\Big(\frac{1}{1+\underbrace{\frac{a_n}{n}}_{\to 0}}+o(1)\Big)\to \exp(1)=e.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We know $(1+1/u)^u \to e$ as $u\to \infty.$ Here's a nice thing to know too: If $x_n \to x \in (0,\infty)$ and $y_n \to y \in \mathbb R,$ then $x_n^{y_n} \to x^y.$ So in our problem we can write

$$(1+1/(n+a_n))^n = [(1+1/(n+a_n))^{n+a_n}]^{n/(n+a_n)}.$$

Because $(a_n)$ is bounded, $n+a_n \to \infty$ and $n/(n+a_n) \to 1.$ Hence the expression in brackets $\to e,$  and the exponent $\to 1.$ Apply the above to  see the limit is $e^1=e.$